# How to make the =GETPIVOTDATA on a data model pivot more dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an Excel pivot table that has the data model as a source.

I'd like to make below formula more dynamic.

```
"=GETPIVOTDATA(""[Measures].[Sum of QTY invoiced]"",Pivot!R3C2,""[Dim_Item_warehouse].[Product Family]"",""[Dim_Item_warehouse].[Product Family].&[Grain]"")"
```

Where I want to replace `""[Dim_Item_warehouse].[Product Family].&[Grain]""` at the end with a cell reference to a column to the left as this cell changes with each row.

How do I do this?

I will use this formula in a VBA Macro filling up some cells with these formula.

Before the pivot had the data model as source i had this:

```
"=GETPIVOTDATA(""12M Sales"",Pivot!R3C2,""Productline"",RC[-1])
```

which is not working anymore.

Comment: Did you try just replacing `""[Dim_Item_warehouse].[Product Family].&[Grain]""` with `RC[-1]` as before?

Comment: I did, with no success..

Comment: What does "no success" actually mean, and what is actually in the cell to the left?

Comment: I get an error message. On the column to the left is a cell with the product family which is 'Grain'. The row below it will be another product line (for example 'Barley').

Comment: In that case you need: `"=GETPIVOTDATA(""[Measures].[Sum of QTY invoiced]"",Pivot!R3C2,""[Dim_Item_warehouse].[Product Family]"",""[Dim_Item_warehouse].[Product Family].&[""&RC[-1]&""]"")"`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks a lot!